# Continuously Update A File

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Ultimately I need to make info from the Spotify API available to an app that will display "current song" info, including cue time.

So will need to be continuously polling the API, as well as updating the data source the App is polling.

I'm still trying to wrap my head around thinking of data in terms of streams as opposed to files.

So I came up with this little experiment for how a file can be continuously updated:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(start=0, step=1):
    f = open('info.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
```

It even sort of works. I can open or `cat info.txt` and intermittently see:

- nothing
- a numeral from an increasing series

Why nothing sometimes?

Additionally confusing, inside the interactive python terminal a stream of slowly incrementing low numerals is output, beginning at 4:

```
4
4
4
4
etc...
5
5
5
5
etc...
```

Is using `f.write` an advisable approach to continuously updating a row of data that can be consumed as a file?

Comment: "Additionally confusing, inside the interactive python terminal a stream of slowly incrementing low numerals is output, beginning at 4:" This is the amount of data that was written by the `.write` call. It increases because the number of digits needed to represent the `i` value increases.

Comment: Would opening the file in append `'a'` mode work for you?

Comment: @ATOMP no because I just want a single row of data.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel so when it is outputting `7` that represents a `7` digit number? Would one potentially generally send the output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import os
import shutil
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(start=0, step=1):
    f = open('tmp', 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
    shutil.move('tmp', 'info.txt')
```

Unlike the open-write-close sequence of operations, the file move is an atomic operation which avoids catching the info.txt file in an "unstable" state i.e. after the open and before the write operation.

Comment: It seems to me that my answer achieves the goal "What would be a dependable example of a continually updating file?". What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why people were down voting. Your example seems to do what I was expecting mine to do.