# How expensive are python file operations? or "How can doing more cost less?"

Tags: python, linux, puzzle

A commenter in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707420/continuously-update-a-file) expressed the opinion that a file move is an expensive operation.

I expected that python uses the Linux mv command which is very fast because it only involves changes to the file system directory, so I decided to investigate the issue by running some tests. The results are shown below.

The first script creates a file 10,000 times:

```
print('-------------------------')
print('Running write_only.py', end='')
for i in range(0,10000):
    f = open('info.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
```

The seconds script also creates a file 10,000 times but, in addition, it includes a file move in the loop:

```
import os
import shutil
print('-------------------------')
print('Running write_and_move.py', end='')
for i in range(0,10000):
    f = open('tmp', 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
    shutil.move('tmp', 'info.txt') # This is the extra move operation
```

(See the post mentioned above for a the original notion behind these scripts.)

At this point I ran the scripts and things *got interesting*:

```
[cp@Lenny so]$ time python3 write_only.py
-------------------------
Running write_only.py
real    0m1.658s
user    0m0.272s
sys     0m0.443s
[cp@Lenny so]$ time python3 write_and_move.py
-------------------------
Running write_and_move.py
real    0m0.690s
user    0m0.256s
sys     0m0.433s
```

What?!!! Not only did the added move operation NOT add to the execution time but the last run took less than the 1/2 the time of the run that did "less work"!

Comment: It's hard to run timing under python because of the unpredictability of garbage collection - ie python decides when to defragment memory, not the program. Your initial run doesn't include a "close" call which might involve more work checking the buffer state etc.

Comment: @Mike I can reproduce that the write_and_move is quicker (although not by as much for me as for the OP), and then adding an explicit close to the write_only makes essentially no difference to the timing.

Comment: I guess that it must just be slower to open an existing file for writing (truncating it) than a new file. EDIT: yes, if I time the syscalls `strace -cT python filename.py` the one that overwrites is definitely spending more time in `open` calls (in fact `openat`).

Comment: @alanivi Bingo! The second script does not have to deal with an existing file.

Comment: @C.Pappy I'm still a bit puzzled though - the `strace` shows that the open calls take a _bit_ longer when there is an existing file, but not by anywhere near enough to offset the time that the `rename` takes. There must be something else going on in user-space when there is an existing file. The move and rename definitely has a greater total time in syscalls.

Comment: @C.Pappy If I use low-level I/O (`os.open`, `os.write`, `os.close`, `os.rename`), then the write and move is certainly the slower of the two - and the same is true with a C program doing low-level I/O. It is *something* that is happening in user-space in python's higher-level file I/O when there is an existing file.

Comment: @alaniwi Very interesting and thanks for the thorough investigation. Are you running 
 the tests on a unix-like os or under Windows?

Comment: @C.Pappy On Ubuntu.

Comment: @alaniwi OK. I will now go ahead and answer my own question and perhaps open a separate topic on unix low level file operations. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I will answer my own question :)

I believe that Python takes longer to create a file when a file by the same name already exists than to rename an existing one, which makes the first script slower.

This script measures how long it takes to create 10,000 *unique* files on my machine:

WARNING! The below script will create 10,000 .txt files in the current directory.

```
    print('-------------------------')
    print('Running write_many.py', end='')
    for i in range(0,10000):
        f = open(f'str({i}).txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(i))
        f.close()

[cp@Lenny so]$ time python3 write_many.py
-------------------------
Running write_many.py
real    0m0.707s
user    0m0.293s
sys     0m0.414s
```

Many thanks to @alaniwi for not only solving the puzzle but, also, for his excellent analysis of Python's behavior.